# Denormalize table and append

Tags: sqlite

How do I denormalize this table

```
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
|  lemma  |                     definition              |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
| abandon |        a feeling of emotional intensity     |
| abandon |        forsake                              |
| abandon |        leave behind                         |
| abbey   |        a church associated with a monastery |
| abbey   |        a convent ruled by an abbess         |
+---------+---------------------------------------------+
```

as

```
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  lemma  |                                      definition                               |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| abandon |        a feeling of emotional intensity forsake leave behind                  |
| abbey   |        a church associated with a monastery a convent ruled by an abbess      |
+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What should be the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT lemma, GROUP_CONCAT(definition, ' ') AS definition
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY lemma
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) is one of the aggregate functions available in SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT lemma, GROUP_CONCAT(definition,' ') 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY lemma
```

Works in SQLite.

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) function

As this link says:

> The group_concat() function returns a string which is the
>   concatenation of all non-NULL values of X. If parameter Y is present
>   then it is used as the separator between instances of X. A comma (",")
>   is used as the separator if Y is omitted. The order of the
>   concatenated elements is arbitrary.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have GROUP_CONCAT function. That link is for MySQL. And the question refers to SQLite

Comment: The query is still syntactically incorrect. You should remove `SEPARATOR`. It should be `GROUP_CONCAT(definition, ' ')`